# How many lines of code is too many for an asp.net mvc3 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller

It depends.

a) Sure, but since the entire project gets turned into one .dll, does it really matter from a performance standpoint if you have 7 controllers with 300 lines of code each versus one controller with 2100 lines? (Obviously readability and tight coupling are problems if there is no separation of concerns)

b) As long as separation of concern is taken into consideration, is the number of lines of code in one controller not an issue?

c) How many lines of code in one controller can be a sign of needing to refactor? (500,1000,5000,10000)?

Comment: You nailed it in your very first sentence. Scrap that other stuff (performance should be the least of your concerns, not to mention that code size rarely affects performance at all - and if it does, it does on an entirely different granularity) and you've answere your own question.

Comment: @delnan - Thanks for the comment, my main concern was with performance which can be an issue with web applications.

Comment: This is a constructive question...it's good to ask what's a good rule of thum...my answer gave specific references and experience. So closing the question was not constructive.

Comment: This isn't all that good in this form.  If you want to try and [edit] to bring this in line with the recommendations in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), it would be ... constructive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good
>   programmers write code that humans can understand.
>   --Martin Fowler [ [source]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)

I remember seeing an application in classic asp that was a single page. It rendered differently based on the parameters that came in. Theoretically, you could do the same thing with ASP.NET MVC, make a single controller with a ton of views (or worse a single view that changed based on input to the controller).

Granted, that super controller divides its work up into actions. But regardless, you're still working with something big.

The first [SOLID Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) is Single Responsibility. Your module should have only one reason to change. A large controller tells me two things:

1. It is involved with too much
2. The actions have too much logic

Both of these are SRP violations because the Controller that does too much has more than one reason to change. The actions that do too much have to change when the logic changes or when the objects they interact with change.

To me a Controller Action should just call a function on a Service (interface, web service, whatever) and return the results of that call. Most of my controller actions are a whopping two lines of code. And most of my controllers are very focused in what they do.

As a rule of thumb, I get uncomfortable when I have to scroll more than two pages for a single class (about 200 lines depending on your font size and/or resolution). Even more important than actual length is how much responsibility my controller has. Minimize the responsibility and file size decreases automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is pretty much in line with what I was curious about. I try not to have more than 300 lines if my controllers, and the actions are definitely as small as possible using Unity as a DI container.

Comment: lol, nice Martin Fowler quote :)